# Open Identify Results Window from QGIS Plugin

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

I am trying to open Identify Results docked window using qgis plugin. How can i open the identify results window using feature id?

I am iterating through active layer, get a specific feature and then open the identify results window automatically within that plugin.